# Windows store app C# XAML - Listview scroll position not maintained when app is resumed

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, scroll, position

I'm Writing a windows store app using C# and XAML.
One of my pages is a split page with a listview where the user can select an item and then the details for that item will be displayed in a "details card" next to the list.

The problem is that the listview doesn't maintain scroll position when I do a suspend and shutdown from Visual studio and then resume the app. The item that was selected is gets selected and it's details are shown but the scroll position is not updated. It works fine with just a suspend and resume.

When I save the state of the page upon suspend I save the selected items index in the list.
When the app is resumed I let LoadState do a MoveCurrentToPosition(selectedIndex) where selectedIndex is the saved index. This makes the correct item selected. I've tried using ScrollIntoView to update the scroll position with no effect.
I had the same problem with the search functionality but in that case ScrollIntoView solved my problem.

Have anyone else encountered this problem? Is it a known problem and what can you do about it when ScrollIntoView doesn't work?

Comment: On the MSDN page there is a comment... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview(v=win.10).aspx "You use the ScrollIntoView method to bring an item into view when the ListViewBase control is not used as a view in a SemanticZoom control. To bring an item into view when the ListViewBase control is used in a SemanticZoom, use the MakeVisible method instead." Could that help?